# MVC in Groovy/Grails

Tags: model-view-controller, grails, groovy

I'm newbie to groovy.
How can we call domain methods from controller in Grails.

Controller :

```
def results = User.fetch_results
```

User Domain :

```
def fetch_results {
    def users = this.get(1)
}
```

Sorry if the above code is wrong, i need to know how to access domain methods from controller.

thanks.

---

My code is like this

UserController:

```
def results = User.addUser
```

User domain:

```
def addUser {
    def user = new User()
    user.id = 1
    user.publication_name = pub_name
    user.publication_desc =  ""
    user.edit_date = new Date()
    user.save()
    }
}
```

I tried with above code but getting errors . how can we call "addUser" method from controller ?

thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to make the method a static method.

```
class User {

    def static addUser() {
        def user = new User()
        ...
        user.save()
    }
}
```

Then make sure to import the User object in your controller.

Comment: Thanks Blacktiger, absolutely i was looking for this solution

Answer (score 0):

I think a

```
User usr = User.get(1) // or User.findBy... etc
```

in your controller should do what you want. Just check out the [GORM documentation](http://grails.org/doc/latest/guide/5.%20Object%20Relational%20Mapping%20%28GORM%29.html) from the [Grails Docs](http://grails.org/doc/latest/), they are really good. If you are new to Groovy but not Java you should check the [Groovy Documentation](http://groovy.codehaus.org/Documentation) before to get a feeling for the Groovy language itself.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you want a list of all users and your domain class is defined as User

```
 def userList=User.list()
```

Assuming you want to access a specific field on user number 2

```
 def theAddress=User.get(1).address
```

Note this assumes you've imported what ever package your domain classes are defined in.